# How to calculate the limit of the sum of this sequence when n is positive infinity?

Tags: calculus

$$S = 
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac1 {2^i + 1}$$
How to calculate this sum?
I calculate it on MatLab and the answer seems to be 0.764499780348444, how to get it?

Comment: What was the original question? Are you sure you actually need to find the sum of this infinite series?

Comment: Yes, the question is asking us to calculate the actual sum of the series.

Comment: It does not have a nice closed form, only in terms of special functions. See [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+1%2F(2%5Ei+%2B+1),+i%3D1..infinity).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not asked to find the actual sum, but just the convergence or divergence of the series. In that case, you may want to use Comparison Test: compare your series with $$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}$$

Comment: Actually I do want to calculate the real sum not only the convergence or divergence.

Comment: @JasonWang Then consult mathematica. check this out. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5Ei%2B1%7D

answer is not really at the calculus level.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
S & \equiv \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{i} + 1} =
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
{1 \over 1 + 2^{i}} + {1 \over 1 - 2^{i}}} -
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over 1 - 2^{i}} =
2\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over 1 - 4^{i}} -
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over 1 - 2^{i}}
\\[5mm] & =
2\,{\psi_{1/4}\pars{1} + \ln\pars{4 - 1} + \ln\pars{1/4} \over \ln\pars{4}} -
{\psi_{1/2}\pars{1} + \ln\pars{2 - 1} + \ln\pars{1/2} \over \ln\pars{2}}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{\ds{%
{\psi_{1/4}\pars{1} - \psi_{1/2}\pars{1} + \ln\pars{3} - \ln\pars{2} \over \ln\pars{2}}}}
\end{align}
$\ds{\psi_{q}\pars{z}}$ is the
[q-Digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html). See expression $\ds{\pars{4}}$ in the cited link.

Comment: @JasonWang You're welcome.